# Youtube API - How to send direct messages to followers?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-plus

According to google support:

> Use Messages to send private messages to other members of the YouTube
>   community. [...] The messages system utilizes Google+
>   messaging so your channel must be connected with a Google+ in order to
>   use this feature.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57955?hl=en

Is it possible to send direct messages to followers via youtube or google plus API?

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest thing that's currently implemented is the `Subscriptions` resource, which

> "contains information about a YouTube user subscription. A
>   subscription notifies a user when new videos are added to a channel or
>   when another user takes one of several actions on YouTube, such as
>   uploading a video, rating a video, or commenting on a video." [[source](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions)]

So your subscribers should be getting a notification when you upload a video or do something similar anyways. If you wanted to message each of them directly, I suppose you could use [`Subscriptions.list()`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) with `mySubscribers` to get your list of subscribers, but I don't think there's a way to mass message them programmatically (seems like it could be easily abused).